# pyspark row number dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe, with columns time,a,b,c,d,val.
I would like to create a dataframe, with additional column, that will contain the row number of the row, within each group, where a,b,c,d is a group key.

I tried with spark sql, by defining a window function, in particular, in sql it will look like this:

```
select time, a,b,c,d,val, row_number() over(partition by a,b,c,d order by     time) as rn from table
group by a,b,c,d,val
```

I would like to do this on the dataframe itslef, without using sparksql.

Thanks

Comment: What to you  mean by _without using sparksql_?

Answer (score 20):

I don't know the python api too much, but I will give it a try. You can try something like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("row_number", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("a","b","c","d").orderBy("time"))).show()
```

Comment: Yes, that's the same as I did, you miss the partition part, df = df.withColumn("id",F.rowNumber().over(Window.partitionBy("a","b","c","d").orderBy(col("time")))), But I would like to do it without that. Thanks

Comment: Note, that spark <=1.6 uses different function name rowNumber()

Comment: Thanks @laguittemh

Comment: @CarlosVilchez is it necessary to use the `orderby` part ? can we just add the `row_number` reserving the natural ordering without ordering it ?

Comment: @Matthew you may need to create a new question for that. There may be some complexities I don't see right off the top of my head, but you need orderby and probably a new column with the row_number to use it.

Comment: Could you create a new question in SO for your case? It would give more visibility to your problem.

Comment: Works pwerfectly. I just had to specify descending order.
 `df.withColumn("rank", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(df["a"]).orderBy(df['time'].desc())))`