# Pyspark add sequential and deterministic index to dataframe

Tags: indexing, pyspark

I need to add an index column to a dataframe with three very simple constraints:

- start from 0
- be sequential
- be deterministic

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious because the examples I'm finding look very convoluted for such a simple task, or use non-sequential, non deterministic increasingly monotonic id's. I don't want to zip with index and then have to separate the previously separated columns that are now in a single column because my dataframes are in the terabytes and it just seems unnecessary. I don't need to partition by anything, nor order by anything, and the examples I'm finding do this (using window functions and row_number). All I need is a simple 0 to df.count sequence of integers. What am I missing here?

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050247/how-do-i-get-a-sql-row-number-equivalent-for-a-spark-rdd?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33102727/primary-keys-with-apache-spark), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46149567/add-sequence-number-column-in-dataframe-usnig-scala), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390721/pyspark-row-number-dataframe), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200217/how-to-create-sequential-number-column-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Comment: DataFrames are inherently unordered. This is one of the core reasons they work for parallel processing- any executor can pick up any part of the data and do its work. You *can* introduce an order (as you've shown), but how can it be deterministic if you don't order by anything?

Comment: Btw, I believe `monotonically_increasing_id` will be deterministic as long as you don't change the number of partitions.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe I'm using the word index out of context here. What I mean is: how can I add a column with an ordered, monotonically increasing by 1 sequence 0:df.count?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What I mean is: how can I add a column with an ordered, monotonically increasing by 1 sequence 0:df.count? [(from comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe#comment91584442_52318016)

You can use `row_number()` here, but for that you'd need to specify an `orderBy()`. Since you don't have an ordering column, just use `monotonically_increasing_id()`.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, monotonically_increasing_id
from pyspark.sql import Window

df = df.withColumn(
    "index",
    row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id()))-1
)
```

Also, `row_number()` starts at 1, so you'd have to subtract 1 to have it start from 0. The last value will be `df.count - 1`.

---

> I don't want to zip with index and then have to separate the previously separated columns that are now in a single column

You *can* use `zipWithIndex` if you follow it with a call to `map`, to avoid having all of the separated columns turn into a single column:

```python
cols = df.columns
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().map(lambda row: (row[1],) + tuple(row[0])).toDF(["index"] + cols
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance but here is a trick.

> Note - *toPandas* will collect all the data to driver

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# speed up toPandas using arrow
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('seq-no') \
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.pyspark.enabled", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled", "true") \
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('id1', "a"),
    ('id2', "b"),
    ('id2', "c"),
], ["ID", "Text"])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(df.toPandas().reset_index()).withColumnRenamed("index","seq_no")

df1.show()

+------+---+----+
|seq_no| ID|Text|
+------+---+----+
|     0|id1|   a|
|     1|id2|   b|
|     2|id2|   c|
+------+---+----+
```

Comment: `df.toPandas()` are you kidding, if to_pandas was a possibility, spark was never used in the first place!

Comment: I have already given note and in some cases when we don't have a choice thats why df.toPandas methods are given