# Add column with row number in increasing order starting from 1 using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to Create a column named "id" which will have row numbers to be used in final pair generation. "id" column

I did it in python using below way. can anyone suggest how to do it in pyspark.

```
con_2['id'] = range(1, 1+len(con_2))
len(con_2.customer_play_id.unique())
```

My Pyspark code is below, but its not working

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
slen = udf(lambda s: len(s), IntegerType())
con_2 = con_2.withColumn('id', F.length(con_2.customer_play_id))
```

expected output should be (Id is the column i want to add)
df

```
id  col1 col2
1   X      Y
2   y1     y4
3   y2     y7
4   y3     y8
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark add sequential and deterministic index to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe)

Answer (score -1):

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window as W
from pyspark.sql import functions as 
con_2 =con_2.withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.orderBy("customer_play_id")))
con_2.show()
```