# Add different arrays from numpy to each row of dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a SparkSQL dataframe and 2D numpy matrix. They have the same number of rows. I intend to add each different array from numpy matrix as a new column to the existing PySpark data frame. In this way, the list added to each row is different.

For example, the PySpark dataframe is like this

```
| Id     | Name   |
| ------ | ------ |
| 1      | Bob    |
| 2      | Alice  |
| 3      | Mike   |
```

And the numpy matrix is like this

```
[[2, 3, 5]
 [5, 2, 6]
 [1, 4, 7]]
```

The resulting expected dataframe should be like this

```
| Id     | Name   | customized_list
| ------ | ------ | ---------------
| 1      | Bob    |   [2, 3, 5]
| 2      | Alice  |   [5, 2, 6]
| 3      | Mike   |   [1, 4, 7]
```

Id column correspond to the order of the entries in the numpy matrix.

I wonder is there any efficient way to implement this?

Comment: does the `Id` column correspond to the order of the entries in the `numpy` matrix?

Comment: Yes, will add it in description

Answer (score 2):

Create a DataFrame from your `numpy` matrix and add an `Id` column to indicate the row number. Then you can join to your original PySpark DataFrame on the `Id` column.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2, 3, 5], [5, 2, 6], [1, 4, 7]])
list_df = spark.createDataFrame(enumerate(a.tolist(), start=1), ["Id", "customized_list"])
list_df.show()
#+---+---------------+
#| Id|customized_list|
#+---+---------------+
#|  1|      [2, 3, 5]|
#|  2|      [5, 2, 6]|
#|  3|      [1, 4, 7]|
#+---+---------------+
```

Here I used `enumerate(..., start=1)` to add the row number.

Now just do an inner join:

```
df.join(list_df, on="Id", how="inner").show()
#+---+-----+---------------+
#| Id| Name|customized_list|
#+---+-----+---------------+
#|  1|  Bob|      [2, 3, 5]|
#|  3| Mike|      [1, 4, 7]|
#|  2|Alice|      [5, 2, 6]|
#+---+-----+---------------+
```

Comment: What's solution if I do not have the identifier like "Id", which is a list of increasing numbers starting from 1.

Comment: @XINLIU then you will have to add an `Id` column: [Pyspark add sequential and deterministic index to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe).