# How to use Pyspark equivalent for reset_index() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'd like to know equivalence in PySpark to the use of `reset_index()` command used in pandas. When using the default command (`reset_index`), as follows:

```
data.reset_index()
```

I get an error:

> "DataFrame' object has no attribute 'reset_index' error"

Comment: Can you provide more to your question - what you are trying to achieve ? what is the expected outcome in  a tabular format ?

Comment: You cannot use reset_index because Spark has not concept of index. The dataframe is distributed and is fundamentally different from pandas.

Comment: If you just want to provide a numerical id to the rows then you can use `monotonically_increasing_id`

Comment: If your problem is as simple as mine this can help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Like the other comments mentioned, if you do need to add an index to your DF, you can use:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id

df = df.withColumn("index_column",monotonically_increasing_id())
```