# How to assign unique ids to entries in a column using PySpark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

For example, if I have a dataframe with a name column, where each name can occur multiple times:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
|Alice |
|Bob   |
|Alice |
|Chloe |
|Chloe |
+------+
```

I want to have a column where each name gets a unique id starting from 0:

```
+------+----+
| name | id |
+------+----+
|Alice | 0  |
|Bob   | 1  |
|Alice | 0  |
|Chloe | 2  |
|Chloe | 2  |
+------+----+
```

How do I achieve this using PySpark? One possible way is to create a data frame with a column of distinct names and assign index such as using `row_number`. But that involves joining back to the original table. So I wonder if there's a direct way to achieve this.

Comment: This should help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318016/pyspark-add-sequential-and-deterministic-index-to-dataframe

Comment: @greenie that post is about adding id for each row, what I want is unique id for each name

Comment: ok :) @algorithman.  Check out StringIndexer. I have added a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions. Logic and code below

```
   new =(df.withColumn('order', row_number().over(Window.partitionBy(lit('1')).orderBy(lit('1'))))#Create increasing id
          .withColumn('id', dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy('name'))-1).orderBy('order')#Use window function; dense_ranl to generate new id
          .drop('order')
         ).show()

+-------+---+
|   name| id|
+-------+---+
|  Alice|  0|
|  Bravo|  1|
|Charlie|  2|
|  Alice|  0|
|  Bravo|  1|
+-------+---+
```

Comment: thanks this works. Just curious, will it be possible to assign id without ordering?  based on the occurrence of name, e.g. if Bravo shows before Alice then bravo will get id 0 and Alice 1

Comment: add these imports:
```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, lit, dense_rank
```

Answer (score 3):

One easy method is to use StringIndexer - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.StringIndexer.html

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", 1), ("Bravo", 2), ("Charlie", 3), ("Alice", 4), ("Bravo", 5)], ["name", "id"])

string_indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol='name', outputCol='index').setHandleInvalid("keep")
model = string_indexer.fit(df)
df_index = model.transform(df).select('id', 'name', col('index').cast('int'))
df_index.show()   
+---+-------+-----+
| id|   name|index|
+---+-------+-----+
|  1|  Alice|    0|
|  2|  Bravo|    1|
|  3|Charlie|    2|
|  4|  Alice|    0|
|  5|  Bravo|    1|

+---+-------+-----+
```

Comment: this is not the fastest solution

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as @wwnde but I hope more readable:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", 1), ("Bravo", 2), ("Charlie", 3), ("Alice", 4), ("Bravo", 5)], ["name", "id"])


# logic
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, lit
from pyspark.sql import Window

def create_index_dataframe(df: pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame, column_name: str) -> pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame:
  df_index = df.select(column_name).distinct()
  w=Window.orderBy(column_name)
  return df_index.withColumn(f"{column_name}_index", row_number().over(w) - lit(1))

df_name_index = create_index_dataframe(df, "name")
df_name_index.show()

+-------+----------+
|   name|name_index|
+-------+----------+
|  Alice|         0|
|  Bravo|         1|
|Charlie|         2|
+-------+----------+


df = df.join(df_name_index, how='left', on=['name'])
df.show()

+-------+---+----------+
|   name| id|name_index|
+-------+---+----------+
|  Alice|  1|         0|
|  Bravo|  2|         1|
|Charlie|  3|         2|
|  Alice|  4|         0|
|  Bravo|  5|         1|
+-------+---+----------+
```